# Partner two grids for scrolling

Tags: extjs

I have two gridpanels, one below each other. When one of the grids scrolls, the other should scroll, too. (Fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16v2))

The issue is that scrolling of the body area works great, but the partner gridpanel's header does not scroll, which it obviously should.

Did I do something utterly wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: You would need to add the partner for the headers too.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thanks for your comment. I have tried to follow it and updated the fiddle accordingly, but it still doesn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a bit in your given fiddle according to @EvanTrimboli suggestion.

Adding following two lines will make the grid headers to scroll properly as well.

```
p1.getView().getScrollable().addPartner(p2.getView().getHeaderCt().getScrollable());
p2.getView().getScrollable().addPartner(p1.getView().getHeaderCt().getScrollable());
```

So adding header of required as partner to the views getScrollable() will work.

Comment: @Alexander You have helped me so many times by answering my questions and various other questions related to ExtJs.
It is an honor for me that I answered your question.